# Three js plane geometry disappears when rotating

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation, mesh

I'm trying to create a very simple scene containing a triangular planar face continuously rotating about the x axis.

Here's the code creating the geometry object, as indicated in this [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020405/basic-2d-colored-triangle-using-three-js/11022909#11022909):

```
// create triangular plane geometry
var geometry_1 = new THREE.Geometry();
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(3,0,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(0,3,0);
geometry_1.vertices.push(v1); 
geometry_1.vertices.push(v2); 
geometry_1.vertices.push(v3);
geometry_1.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 1, 2));
```

The animation function renders the scene and adds a small rotation to the mesh:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    mesh_1.rotation.x += 0.005;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

Everything works fine until the value of `mesh.rotation.x` goes into the `[Math.PI, 2*Math.PI]` interval, at which point it disappears for exactly half of the cycle. This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sjc1kbe/3/) replicates the behavior I'm observing.

- This is not a `light` problem, as there are an ambient light and a directional light supposed to illuminate the mesh at all points of it revolution.
- This should not be a `material` problem, as I did set its `side` property to `THREE.DoubleSide` and in fact in the interval `mesh.rotation.x` into `[0, Math.PI]` I already observe both faces.
- I tried adding another face to the same geometry with `geometry_1.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 1));` but that still didn't solve the problem.
- Adding a second geometry with an opposite face `geometry_2.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(0, 2, 1));` and having the mesh rotate negatively `mesh_2.rotation.x -= 0.005;` allows me to observe the desired result because the two geometries are now disappearing in opposite halves of the `[0, 2*Math.PI]` interval. This however is a hacky and not ideal solution.

So what is going on? How can I solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera) says:

`OrthographicCamera( left, right, top, bottom, near, far )`

so, set your camera like this:

```
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, 
                                       FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, -FRUSTUM_SIDE/2);
```

thus you'll have default `near` and `far` camera frustrum planes (0.1 and 2000).

Explanation: You set your cam at z-position, which is equal to `FRUSTRUM_SIDE/2` and also you set your `far` camera frustrum plane with the same value. So you see everything between your cam position and the distance from it, which is `FRUSTRUM_SIDE/2`. In world coordinates, your far plane is at point (0, 0, 0). That's why your triangle disappears when it goes further then the distance of `FRUSTRUM_SIDE/2` from your cam.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm confused about one thing. I put my camera on z=+10, shouldn't I see from +10 to -10? Why am I effectively seeing from +10 to 0?My understanding was that the camera would see everything that is between near and far, is that wrong?

Comment: You seem to suggest (and the example not working shows) that the camera sees everything between its position and far. Why is that? Isn't that contradicting what this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3adBAnDpos) says?

Comment: Because documentation says: _Camera frustum near plane. Default is 0.1. The valid range is between 0 and the current value of the far plane. Note that, unlike for the PerspectiveCamera, 0 is a valid value for an OrthographicCamera's near plane. _ So, set your camera frustrum near plane at 0 and far plane at `FRUSTRUM_SIDE`: `camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, -FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, 0, FRUSTUM_SIDE);`. And mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your problem, please )

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from @prisoner849, the problem shown in the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sjc1kbe/3/) has nothing to do with the geometry or the material of the mesh, but with the shape and extension of the frustum defined by the `OrthographicCamera`.

As explained nicely in this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k3adBAnDpos) and in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/cameras/OrthographicCamera) the frustum of an `OrthographicCamera` is a rectangular parallelepiped defined by the values `left, right, top, bottom, near, far`:

[image]

The camera should effectively be thought of as being attached to the surface on the near side and facing towards negative values of the `z axis`.

Once the frustum's shape is defined with:

```
FRUSTUM_SIDE = 20;
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
   -FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, 
   FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, -FRUSTUM_SIDE/2,
   -FRUSTUM_SIDE/2, FRUSTUM_SIDE/2);
```

we will be able to see in our image all the objects in the scene which are entirely contained in it.

However, after defining the frustum the position of the camera is changed: `camera.position.z = FRUSTUM_SIDE/2;` (line 24 of the fiddle). This effectively moves the whole frustum and not just the location of the image, so while previously any object in `(0,0,0)` was in the center of the frustum, now it will lie on the very far end plane of it.

The animation function:

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    mesh_1.rotation.x += 0.005;
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

rotates the triangle towards the image plane, but for angles between `[Math.PI, 2*Math.PI]` the plane is effectively pointing outside of the frustum and thus becomes invisible.

Removing the `camera.position.z = FRUSTUM_SIDE/2;` line, or defining a different frustum, or moving the mesh position to the middle of the new frustum are all possible solutions. I.e. [corrected fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9sjc1kbe/4/).